# What is the syntax error in Create table statement?

Tags: sql, database, create-table

I'm sorry if this is too easy, but I'm tired and cannot seem to solve this on my own. Can anyone see what is wrong with this command?

```
create table Users (
   user_id NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY ,
   username VARCHAR2(16) NOT NULL,
   password VARCHAR2(16) NOT NULL,
   first_name VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
   last_name VARCHAR2(20) NUT NULL,
);
```

**Edit:** Thanks all. Problem solved. It was the last comma and the NUT :P

Comment: oracle, right? if so, i think NUMBER doesn't need the (4)

Comment: Which database software are you trying to create this table in? What error message do you get?

Comment: You've got an extra comma after the last column declaration. You've also put "NUT" instead of "NOT" on the last column too!

Comment: oh and NUT is a word for crazy :) (last line)

Comment: Also, you appear to have a typo -- "NUT" instead of "NOT"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do this

```
create table Users (
    user_id numeric(4) PRIMARY KEY ,
    username VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
```

I Changed:

- `number` to `numeric`
- removed last comma
- `varchar2` to `varchar`
- `NUT` to `NOT`

Comment: I'm using Oracle Express Edition, can you tell me whats the difference between the one I used and the ones you used?

Comment: what is the difference between varchar2 and varchar here

Comment: @AliBassam: [Here is an overview](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-datatypes.html). You can use your data types. You did not specify which DB engine you are using and `NUMBER` and `VARCHAR2` are not available on all DB Engines. Since you are using Oracle these types are fine too.

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the last comma and change `NUT` to `NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
create table Users (
    user_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY ,
    username VARCHAR2(16) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR2(16) NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Im assuming this is for SQL SERVER?

```
   CREATE TABLE Users ( 
        user_id INT PRIMARY KEY 
    ,   username VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL
    ,   [password] VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL
    ,   first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    ,   last_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL 
    )
```

Comment: error is- right syntax to use near '[password] VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL , first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL , ' at line 4